# How Can I Sort the [Array] Value Elements in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can I filter the count and quality fields,[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fwFnc4rMB3R8SVjlzqz1?p=preview)   **For example**:- In the Count drop down list is `yarn count , carn count ,burn count`.. if I select the `yarn count` that particular transaction only need to display....Please look at my plunker and  help us.[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fwFnc4rMB3R8SVjlzqz1?p=preview)

How I should customize My JSON to work with the array inside an array (or) How I should make `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat` to achieve above given scenario.

**My Html :-**

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default"> 
   <label>Count</label> 
     <select data-ng-model="searchtable.count" id="count" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control">
         <option value="">All</option>
         </select>
    </div>
```

And

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default">
  <label>Quality</label>
     <select data-ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].quality for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control"  >
        <option value="">All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

**My data-ng-model:-**

```
 data-ng-model="searchtable.count"
```

And

```
 data-ng-model="searchtable.quality"
```

**My Filter code:-**

```
filter:searchtable.count.colorshades[0].count

filter:searchtable.quality.colorshades[0].quality
```

**My Data:-**

```
    $scope.sryarnorders = [
   {
"_id": "579ef3adba3bac040b583b4f",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 1,
"colorshades": [
{
"_id": "579ef3feba3bac040b583b51",
"quality": "Home Textiles",
"count": "carn count"
},

{
"_id": "579ef3feba3bac040b583b50",
"quality": "Hall Textiles",
"count": "yarn count"
}
],
"created": "2016-08-01T07:01:01.181Z",
"ex_india_date": "2016-08-08",
"supplier_name": "Msd",
"buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
},
{
"_id": "5768e6c8bdbc5db509f0f2b2",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 1,
"colorshades": [
{
"_id": "5768e6fcbdbc5db509f0f2b3",
"quality": "Hall Textiles",
"count": "carn count"
}
],
"created": "2016-06-21T07:03:36.504Z",
"ex_india_date": "2016-06-22",
"supplier_name": "Msd",
"buyer_name": "Rohit"
},

{
"_id": "5767cd78f5012d790aa41a7b",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 3,
"colorshades": [
{
"_id": "5767ce37f5012d790aa41a7c",
"quality": "yarn quality",
"count": "burn count"
}
],
"created": "2016-06-20T11:03:20.382Z",
"ex_india_date": "2016-06-21",
"supplier_name": "Mani selvam",
"buyer_name": "ms"
}
```

I have created Plunker for reference:- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fwFnc4rMB3R8SVjlzqz1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select model always returns the full object in the array, not what you set as value. For example, when selecting "yarn count" in your plunker, `searchtable.count` equals to

```
{"_id":"573d7fa0760ba711126d7de5","user":{"_id":"5721a378d33c0d6b0bb30416","displayName":"ms ms"},"__v":1,"colorshades":[{"_id":"573d7fc3760ba711126d7de6","quality":"Home Textiles","count":"yarn count"},{"_id":"579ef3feba3bac040b583b50","color":"56a5b6831746bc1c0b391c7c","quality":"Hall Textiles","count":"carn count"}],"created":"2016-05-19T08:56:00.997Z","actual_delivery_date":"2016-05-19","ex_india_date":"2016-05-19","ex_factory_date":"2016-05-19","po_delivery_date":"2016-05-19","supplier_name":"Fsa","buyer_name":"e21"}
```

Given this, there are two solutions:

#### 1. Filter accordingly

Filter like that:

```
| filter:searchtable.count.colorshades[0].count | filter:searchtable.quality.colorshades[0].quality
```

Which doesn't look clean.

#### 2. Changing Options

You can also change the `ng-options` like this:

```
item.colorshades[0].count as item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders
```

Which will make ng-model return only `item.colorshades[0].count`. You will still have to adjust the filter:

```
| filter:searchtable.count | filter:searchtable.quality
```

It might be possible to make that cleaner, I am going to have to look into that.

Comment: Hey Thank you soo much for your valuable comment it's working perfectly in plunker as well, but it's not working in my `local host` ...do you know why it's not working ?...

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. Could you give me a little more detail? The JSON originates from MongoDB, right?

Comment: Hey here we have updated not working plunker :- http://plnkr.co/edit/fwFnc4rMB3R8SVjlzqz1?p=preview so please look at that , and provide the solution why it's not working and where i did the mistake please help .......

Comment: Here is working plunker for your referrence:- http://plnkr.co/edit/YR5Di3yYtxJi0GvKGTE4?p=preview  please look at both and provide the solution....thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Yes Finnaly I have Found the solution, What I did changed the `ng-module` , and `filter`.... [my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BPaQFsvKNtttN3UywlaS?p=preview)...